# Attachment Size Limitation in Redemption RDOMail

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption, msg, eml

I am using Redemption in my code to convert an eml file to msg file.
I am using Import method to do so.

However, i observed that for one of the eml file which has an attachment of size 500mb+, the file does get converted to msg file but the large attachment is skipped.

Is there any size limitation for attachments?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no intrinsic limitations. But MSG files, being OLE store (IStorage) files may impose limitations on the number of substreams used for storing recipients and attachments, especially in 32 bit.

Check to see if the import work correctly for a message in an Outlooks folder rather than a standalone MSG file.